# Inplace transformation pandas with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, in-place

Would it be possible to mutate DataFrame **inplace** with `groupby` statement?

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.DataFrame({
                   "LETTER": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"],
                   "VALUE" : [10 , 12 , 13,  0,  15]
                   })
def __add_new_col(dt_):
    dt_['NEW_COL'] = dt_['VALUE'] - dt_['VALUE'].mean()
    return dt_
pass


dt.groupby("LETTER").apply(__add_new_col)
  LETTER  VALUE  NEW_COL
0      a     10      5.0
1      b     12     -1.5
2      c     13      0.0
3      a      0     -5.0
4      b     15      1.5


dt
  LETTER  VALUE
0      a     10
1      b     12
2      c     13
3      a      0
4      b     15
```

In R data.table it is possible by using `:=` operator e.g. `dt[, col := ... , by ='LETTER']`

Comment: Why not `df['NEWCOL'] = dt.groupby('LETTER')['VALUE'].apply(lambda x: x - x.mean())`?

Comment: @JohnGalt Is there an order guarantee?

Comment: Yes, you can validate it yourself too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) which return `Series` same length and same index as `df` with substracting:

```
print (dt.groupby("LETTER")['VALUE'].transform('mean'))
0     5.0
1    13.5
2    13.0
3     5.0
4    13.5
Name: VALUE, dtype: float64

dt['NEW_COL'] = dt['VALUE'] - dt.groupby("LETTER")['VALUE'].transform('mean')
print (dt)
  LETTER  VALUE  NEW_COL
0      a     10      5.0
1      b     12     -1.5
2      c     13      0.0
3      a      0     -5.0
4      b     15      1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure you can't mutate the dataframe during a group by. You can do exactly the same operation mapping every lettering with it's mean and then perform the operation.

```
df['NEW_COL'] = df['VALUE'] - df['LETTER'].map(dt.groupby("LETTER")['VALUE'].mean()).values
```

This will deal with any possible ordering issue, which I wouldn't trust to be guarantee even if tested. Better safe than sorry :)

Also, I'm using **.values** accessor after the map because I'm not sure what the index of the "mapped" series will be the same of the 'VALUE' series, which sometime will result with NaN.